# Expected values conditioning two different expressions of a discrete variable

Tags: linear-model, conditional-expectation

Suppose that we have two continuous random variables $Y$ and $X$ and a discrete random variable $W$.

The discrete variable $W$ can have only three values 1, 2, or 3. That is, $Supp(W)=\left\{1,2,3\right\}$.

Next, define a binary variable $D=\mathbf{1}\left[W>1\right]$.

In this setup, I am considering a linear model:
$$Y=X'\beta+u,$$
where $u$ is an error term with zero mean.

Then, let's consider two conditional means of $Y$:
\begin{align*}
&\mathbb{E}\left[Y\middle|X,D=1\right]=X'\beta+\mathbb{E}\left[u\middle|X,D=1\right] \\[5pt]
&\mathbb{E}\left[Y\middle|X,W=2\;or\;3\right]=X'\beta+\mathbf{1}\left[W=2\right]\cdot\mathbb{E}\left[u\middle|X,W=2\right]+\mathbf{1}\left[W=3\right]\cdot\mathbb{E}\left[u\middle|X,W=3\right]
\end{align*}
Here, I think, since $D=1 \Leftrightarrow W>1 \Leftrightarrow W=2\;or\;3$, the left-hand-sides should be the same. That is, the following equality should hold.
$$\mathbb{E}\left[Y\middle|X,D=1\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[Y\middle|X,W=2\;or\;3\right]$$
and thus the following equality $(1)$ should hold
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[u\middle|X,D=1\right]=\mathbf{1}\left[W=2\right]\cdot\mathbb{E}\left[u\middle|X,W=2\right]+\mathbf{1}\left[W=3\right]\cdot\mathbb{E}\left[u\middle|X,W=3\right]\qquad(1)
$$
However, we can write the left-hand side above as
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[u\middle|X,D=1\right]&=\mathbb{E}\left[u\middle|X,W>1\right] \\[5pt]
&=\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left(u\middle|X,W>1,W\right)\middle|X,W>1\right] \\[5pt]
&=\mathbb{E}\left(u\middle|X,W>1,W=2\right)\cdot\Pr\left(W=2\middle|X,W>1\right) \\[5pt]
&+\mathbb{E}\left(u\middle|X,W>1,W=3\right)\cdot\Pr\left(W=3\middle|X,W>1\right)
\end{align*}
and it shows that equality $(1)$ does not hold.

So, I think, I made some mistakes, but I cannot find that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first derivation you have the step
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[u\middle|X,W=2\;or\;3\right]=\mathbf{1}\left[W=2\right]\cdot\mathbb{E}\left[u\middle|X,W=2\right]+\mathbf{1}\left[W=3\right]\cdot\mathbb{E}\left[u\middle|X,W=3\right]
$$
which doesn't look right.

You can see that because the conditional expectation on the LHS is a function of $X$ alone, whereas the RHS is a function of both $X$ and $W$ (because of the indicator functions).

The second derivation looks correct to me.

Comment: That is a good point. I did not realize that. As you said, the first derivation is incorrect. Thank you so much.